# Receiving random cost output on tensorflow regression- python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am relatively new to tensorflow and I have attempted to adapt some code from a tutorial to process my own data.

The data can be found here: https://github.com/z12332/tensorflow-test-1/blob/master/export.csv

Keep in mind, that the dataset being fed consists of only columns 9 though 27 (with nan's converted to 0) and column 30 as the labels

here is the link to the tutorial code: https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_use_Tensorflow_for_classification-LIVE/blob/master/demo.ipynb

I am able to get the program to run without an error message, but for some reason, it outputs 200 training steps of relatively random cost values. As and example, here are the first few steps:

```
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.039999638
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.159996599
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000002
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000004
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000001
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.039994366
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000005
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.039997347
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.359970629
Training step: 0000 cost= 1.959837437
Training step: 0000 cost= 3.239814520
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000195
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000228
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000003
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.000000388
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.039958697
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.159986690
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.159973413

Training cost= 2.70406e-05 W= [  2.38201610e-05   1.96683395e-05   3.69497479e-06   2.77944509e-05
   2.02058782e-05   3.82550934e-05   3.37507554e-05   2.18498894e-06
   2.92303273e-04   7.17514267e-05   2.34498725e-06   3.40497172e-06
   6.25661269e-05   5.59996465e-07   8.81450160e-06   3.44998034e-06] b= [  2.62004360e-05]
```

Here is my code in full, for anyone knows why this is happening or how to debug:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/benny/desktop/export.csv')
data_ = df.iloc[1:,9:27]
data_['CRISPR'] = df.iloc[:,30]
data_ = data_.drop(['Diseases'],axis=1)

dim = 16
learning_rate = 0.0000001
display_step = 50

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

train_X = data_.iloc[:200, :-2].as_matrix()

''' 
dimensions = [200,16]

array([[ 25.,   2.,   3., ...,  nan,  nan,   2.],
       [  5.,  13.,   3., ...,  nan,  19.,   2.],
       [ 25.,  13.,   3., ...,  nan,  nan,   2.],
       ..., 
       [ 25.,  13.,   3., ...,  nan,  nan,   2.],
       [ 25.,  13.,   3., ...,  nan,  nan,   2.],
       [ nan,  13.,   3., ...,  nan,  19.,   3.]])
'''
train_X = train_X.fillna(value=0)

train_Y = data_.iloc[:200, -1].as_matrix()

'''
dimensions = [200]

array([ 1,  2,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  3,  7,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,
        2,  0,  0,  0,  7,  2,  2,  2,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  5,  2,
        1,  2,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  2,  1,  2,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,
        1,  3,  1,  2,  4,  1,  0,  1,  6,  2,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,
        1,  7,  7,  4,  1,  1,  6,  4,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  2,
        0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  3,  2,  3,  1,  1,  9,  7,  4,  1,  1,  1,
        0,  1,  5,  4,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  4,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,
        1,  2,  1,  4,  0, 10,  2,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        3,  1,  1,  2,  0,  7,  0,  2,  0,  2,  0,  0,  2,  3,  1,  0,  7,
        3,  2,  9,  1,  0,  0,  2,  1,  0,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  4,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  4,  1,  0,  0,  1, 15,  1,  0,  1,  2,
        0,  0,  1,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  2,  1,  0,  1, 11])

'''


test_X = data_.iloc[200:320, :-2].as_matrix()
test_Y = data_.iloc[200:320, -1].as_matrix()

n_samples = train_Y.size

W= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="bias")

activation = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)


cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(activation-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

hm_epochs = 10

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

xy = zip(train_X, train_Y) 
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for (x, y) in xy:
    for i in range(hm_epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x[np.newaxis, ...],
                                       Y: y[np.newaxis, ...]})

        if (i) % display_step == 0:
            cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x[np.newaxis, ...],
                                           Y: y[np.newaxis, ...]})
            print "Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc)

print "Optimization Finished!"
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:x[np.newaxis, ...],
                                          Y:y[np.newaxis, ...]})
print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'
```

Could the random values be from the missing values (changed to 0 in the dataset)? Also, how would I now apply the test_X,Y dataframes to predict?

Either way Im here to learn so thanks for your help!

Comment: try debugging ny converting nans to 0. let us know what happens.

Comment: @putonspectacles Alright thanks! so now it is outputting the cost, but still 205 steps of `Training step: 0000` rather than 10 of 1 though 10

Comment: In addition, the costs seem to be completely random, not decreasing as they go. Is this a problem?

Comment: in general the cost should be decreasing. would love to continue helping you debug, can you share some of your data?

Comment: to debug the printing error try changing printing just the variable i without any formatting. (btw) you dont need the parentheses in `if (i) % display_step==0`

Comment: also can you point us to where you're adapting the code from?

Comment: @putonspectacles The post has been updated with the code source and a github link to the full data file :)) In regards to the debug, it now just outputs 200 0's

Comment: I added an answer that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of the code, but before I'll offer some notes.

1) One do some reading at [tensorflow mnist tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). 
Im particular see why your placeholder sizes are not correct and why 
we are going to use a one-hot-encoded version of the labels for this task.

2) Consider using cross-entropy cost. It is a more well suited cost
 for this multiclass task.

3) try not to be too underwhelmed by the performance of this basic model
 (it does not perform well). Consider exploring the data looking for import features and also look around for what the state of the art performance on this dataset
might be.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/benny/desktop/export.csv')
data_ = df.iloc[1:,9:27]
data_['CRISPR'] = df.iloc[:,30]
data_ = data_.drop(['Diseases'],axis=1)
# we will need the number of classes to be predict
# the nunique methods gets us the number of unique labels
nclasses = data["CRISPR"].nunique()
# lets collect of labels here. We'll one-hot-encode them
# using pandas.get_dummies()
inputY = pd.get_dummies(data_.iloc[:, -1])

dim = 16
learning_rate = 0.0000001
display_step = 50

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim])
# Y should define the shape of your labels. 
# As discussed we're going to need one hot encoded labels for
# this prediction task. this line does not define the shape of your input.
# we'll define later
# Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


train_X = data_.iloc[:200, :-2].as_matrix()
train_X = train_X.fillna(value=0)
train_Y = inputY[:200].as_matrix()

test_X = data_.iloc[200:320, :-2].as_matrix()
test_Y = inputY[200:320].as_matrix()

n_samples = train_Y.size

# Its important we get the shape of the weight and bias matrices
# correct, the version in code is:
# W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim]), name="weight")
# that wont work since we want to be able to multiply [X, W]
# to produce a evidence vector for each each example. 
# the shape of X is [200 x dim] - there should be a weight for each 
# feature and there 10 classes so  W is [dim, nclasses],
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim, nclasses]))

# for the bias, there should be one for each class.
# b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="bias")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nclasses]))

# the correct operation here is tf.matmal, I suspect you introduced
# this to make your early matrix definiton work in the graph
# activation = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
activation = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b) 

# you forgot the actual model! Assuming you want to do
# softmax classification let do:
y = tf.nn.softmax(activation)
# Now let's define or input labels ( we could have called them Y )
# as you had them. Notice what we are saying here is expect a matrix
# of floats with any number of examples and nclasses number of columns
# which is exactly the size of train_Y.  
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nclasses])


# we define the cost reflect the fact that our model output is called
# y not activations (anymore)
# cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(activation-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_ - y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

hm_epochs = 1000

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# I imagine what you want to do here is stochastic gradient descent. 
# I am not sure this is the way to do it. End to check the code I 
# will train over the entire training data for 1000 repetitions, 
# similar to the tutorial code.
# .....
for i in range(hm_epochs):
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_X,
                               y_: train_Y})

    if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X,y_: train_Y})
        print "Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc)


# To check the accuracy ( this is one way of measuring the performance 
# of an algorithm on a classification task) we will do: (This is 
# adapted from the tensflow mnist example [code][1]) 

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_X,
                              y_: test_Y}))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am recievig this error when trying to run the session: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (200,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 13)'` Any Ideas?

Comment: The error was actually after I had fixed that issue. hmm

Comment: there was an error when indexing inputY. It should be train_Y = inputY[:200] not train_Y = inputY[:200, -1]

Comment: Awesome! It ran!! (Although with 41% accuracy I need to rethink some things) Thank you!

Comment: Hi again, would you mind looking at my follow up question to see if you know the newest issue I am having? Thanks!