# Improving Accuracy of a Tensorflow neural network- python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification

This is a continuation of my first question: [Receiving random cost output on tensorflow regression- python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466123/receiving-random-cost-output-on-tensorflow-regression-python/42476325#42476325)

I am using a multi-layered perceptron ANN to predict the Phyla of bacteria samples based on other observed data. Every time I run my code I get an accuracy of 0. The dataset is not the best as there are plenty of NaN's (that have been replaced with 0), but I expected better than nothing. I am looking for help to debug and improved accuracy

The dataset that I am currently using can be found here: 
https://github.com/z12332/tensorflow-test-1/blob/master/export.csv

This is my current code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.contrib import learn

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/zach/desktop/export.csv')
data_ = df.drop(['ID'], axis=1)


n_classes = data_["Phylum"].nunique()

inputY = pd.get_dummies(data_['Phylum'])

dim = 19
learning_rate = 0.000001
display_step = 50
n_hidden_1 = 500
n_hidden_2 = 500
n_hidden_3 = 500
n_hidden_4 = 500

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim])


train_X = data_.iloc[:2000, :-1].as_matrix()
train_X = pd.DataFrame(data=train_X)
train_X = train_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

train_Y = inputY.iloc[:2000].as_matrix()
train_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=train_Y)
train_Y = train_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

test_X = data_.iloc[2000:, :-1].as_matrix()
test_X = pd.DataFrame(data=test_X)
test_X = test_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

test_Y = inputY.iloc[2000:].as_matrix()
test_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=test_Y)
test_Y = test_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

n_samples = train_Y.size
total_len = train_X.shape[0]
n_input = train_X.shape[1]
batch_size = 10


W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim, n_classes]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
     out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
     return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
cost = -tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(pred,1e-10,1.0)))
optimizer =     tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
hm_epochs = 500

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 

    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch-1):
            batch_x = train_X[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = train_Y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]

            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={X: batch_x,   
                                                               y: batch_y})
        avg_cost += c / total_batch

    label_value = batch_y
    estimate = p
    err = label_value-estimate

    if epoch % display_step == 0:
        print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
            "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        print ("[*]----------------------------")
        for i in xrange(3):
            print ("label value:", label_value[i], \
                    "estimated value:", estimate[i])
        print ("[*]============================")

print ("Optimization Finished!")

# Test model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: test_X, y: test_Y}))
```

My output completes as such:

```
Epoch: 0451 cost= 72.070914993
[*]----------------------------
label value: [0 1 0 0 0] estimated value: [ 1184.01843262 -1293.13989258    99.68536377   655.67803955  -833.19824219]
label value: [0 1 0 0 0] estimated value: [ 1183.1940918  -1273.7635498     95.80528259   656.42572021  -841.03656006]
label value: [0 1 0 0 0] estimated value: [ 1183.55383301 -1304.3470459     96.90409088   660.52886963  -838.37719727]
[*]============================
Optimization Finished!
Accuracy: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! In order to improve accuracy, it is necessary to break the train and test batches into random samples, else the network will not process necessary data and will fail. I have implemented this by rewriting the data formatting section as such:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/zach/desktop/export.csv')
data_ = df.drop(['ID','Species'], axis=1)


n_classes = data_["Phylum"].nunique()

dim = 18
learning_rate = 0.0001
display_step = 10
n_hidden_1 = 2000
n_hidden_2 = 1500
n_hidden_3 = 1000
n_hidden_4 = 500

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim])

train_set = data_.sample(frac=0.75) #THIS ADDITION SPLITS THE DATA RANDOMLY AND TAKE 75% FOR TRAINING
test_set = data_.loc[~data_.index.isin(train_set.index)] #THIS TAKES THE REMAINING DATA FOR TESTING

train_size = train_set.size

inputY_test = pd.get_dummies(test_set['Phylum'])
inputY_train = pd.get_dummies(train_set['Phylum'])

train_X = train_set.iloc[:train_size, :-1].as_matrix()
train_X = pd.DataFrame(data=train_X)
train_X = train_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

train_Y = inputY_train.as_matrix()
train_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=train_Y)
train_Y = train_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

test_X = test_set.iloc[:, :-1].as_matrix()
test_X = pd.DataFrame(data=test_X)
test_X = test_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

test_Y = inputY_test.as_matrix()
test_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=test_Y)
test_Y = test_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()
```

With these edits a simple run of 50 epochs, taking about 2 minutes, predicted the correct result with an accuracy of 91.4%