# Encoding a TensorFlow neural network into tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tensorflow

If you have seen my other questions, you might know I am currently working on developing a classification ANN using Tensorflow. I have developed the network to my contentment and am now working on building a simple user interface for those who are not familiar with python to use the network for classification.

Has anyone encoded a Tensorflow ANN into Tkinter? Presumably, the GUI would ask for all of the features that lead to predicting the final case, run those through the network, and output the most likely case.

I guess my main question is, has anyone successfully done this? If so, how does one go about encoding the network withing the GUI itself? Any tips are appreciated.

For my code, please see this post: [Improving Accuracy of a Tensorflow neural network- python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804580/improving-accuracy-of-a-tensorflow-neural-network-python)

Comment: Help? Thanks peeps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. All that really needs to be done is place the entire network model within the function of a button in Tkinter. What I've done here is allow the features to be inputs for the `test` data through simple `Entry()` boxes.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#from tensorflow.contrib import learn

#from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
#from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

from Tkinter import *

print 'Initiallize Program'

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Bacteria Classification Program")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        bar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = bar)

        Label_Main = Label(self.master, text='Please Enter Data Below', fg='red')
        Label_Main.place(x=120, y=2)

        file = Menu(bar)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
        bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

        xdim = 150
        xdimL = 5

        mEntry1 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent1)
        mEntry1.place(x=xdim,y=30)

        Label1 = Label(self.master, text = 'Biotic Relationship')
        Label1.place(x=xdimL, y=30)

        mEntry2 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent2)
        mEntry2.place(x=xdim,y=60)

        Label2 = Label(self.master, text = 'Cell Arrangement')
        Label2.place(x=xdimL, y=60)

        mEntry3 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent3)
        mEntry3.place(x=xdim, y=90)

        Label3 = Label(self.master, text = 'Cell Shape')
        Label3.place(x=xdimL, y=90)

        mEntry4 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent4)
        mEntry4.place(x=xdim,y=120)

        Label4 = Label(self.master, text = 'Ecosystem')
        Label4.place(x=xdimL, y=120)

        mEntry5 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent5)
        mEntry5.place(x=xdim, y=150)

        Label5 = Label(self.master, text = 'Ecosystem Category')
        Label5.place(x=xdimL, y=150)

        mEntry6 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent6)
        mEntry6.place(x=xdim, y=180)

        Label6 = Label(self.master, text = 'Ecosystem Subtype')
        Label6.place(x=xdimL, y=180)

        mEntry7 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent7)
        mEntry7.place(x=xdim, y=210)

        Label2 = Label(self.master, text = 'Ecosystem Type')
        Label2.place(x=xdimL, y=210)

        mEntry8 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent8)
        mEntry8.place(x=xdim, y=240)

        Label8 = Label(self.master, text = 'Energy Source')
        Label8.place(x=xdimL, y=240)

        mEntry9 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent9)
        mEntry9.place(x=xdim, y=270)

        Label9 = Label(self.master, text = 'Gram Staining')
        Label9.place(x=xdimL, y=270)

        mEntry10 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent10)
        mEntry10.place(x=xdim, y=300)

        Label10 = Label(self.master, text = 'Habitat')
        Label10.place(x=xdimL, y=300)

        mEntry11 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent11)
        mEntry11.place(x=xdim, y=330)

        Label11 = Label(self.master, text = 'Motility')
        Label11.place(x=xdimL, y=330)

        mEntry12 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent12)
        mEntry12.place(x=xdim, y=360)

        Label12 = Label(self.master, text = 'Oxygen Requirement')
        Label12.place(x=xdimL, y=360)

        mEntry13 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent13)
        mEntry13.place(x=xdim, y=390)

        Label13 = Label(self.master, text = 'Sporulation')
        Label13.place(x=xdimL, y=390)

        mEntry14 = Entry(self,textvariable=ent14)
        mEntry14.place(x=xdim, y=420)

        Label14 = Label(self.master, text = 'Temperature Range')
        Label14.place(x=xdimL, y=420)

        entButton = Button(self, text="Run Network", command=self.enter_value)
        entButton.place(x=130,y=460)


    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def enter_value(self):
        mtext1 = ent1.get()
        mtext2 = ent2.get()
        mtext3 = ent3.get()
        mtext4 = ent4.get()
        mtext5 = ent5.get()
        mtext6 = ent6.get()
        mtext7 = ent7.get()
        mtext8 = ent8.get()
        mtext9 = ent9.get()
        mtext10 = ent10.get()
        mtext11 = ent11.get()
        mtext12 = ent12.get()
        mtext13 = ent13.get()
        mtext14 = ent14.get()


        test_X = np.array([mtext1,mtext2,mtext3,mtext4,mtext5,mtext6,mtext7,mtext8,mtext9,
                          mtext10,mtext11,mtext12,mtext13,mtext14])#.reshape(1,14)


        print 'Entry:', test_X 


        df = pd.read_csv('/Users/zach/desktop/export.csv')
        data_ = df.drop(['ID','Species'], axis=1)


        n_classes = data_["Phylum"].nunique()

        dim = 14
        learning_rate = 0.0001
        display_step = 10
        n_hidden_1 = 2000
        n_hidden_2 = 1500
        n_hidden_3 = 1000
        n_hidden_4 = 500

        X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim])

        train_set = data_.sample(frac=1)
        test_set = data_.loc[~data_.index.isin(train_set.index)]

        train_size = train_set.size

        inputY_test = pd.get_dummies(test_set['Phylum'])
        inputY_train = pd.get_dummies(train_set['Phylum'])

        train_X = train_set.iloc[:train_size, 5:].as_matrix()
        train_X = pd.DataFrame(data=train_X)
        train_X = train_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

        train_Y = inputY_train.as_matrix()
        train_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=train_Y)
        train_Y = train_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

        #test_X = test_set.iloc[:, 5:].as_matrix()
        #test_X = pd.DataFrame(data=test_X)
        #test_X = test_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()
        test_X = pd.DataFrame(data=test_X)
        test_X = test_X.replace('', np.nan)
        test_X = test_X.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()
        test_X.resize(1,14)


        test_Y = inputY_test.as_matrix()
        test_Y = pd.DataFrame(data=test_Y)
        test_Y = test_Y.fillna(value=0).as_matrix()

        n_samples = train_Y.size
        total_len = train_X.shape[0]
        n_input = train_X.shape[1]
        batch_size = 5


        W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim, n_classes]))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))


        def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
            # Hidden layer with RELU activation
            layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
            layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

            # Hidden layer with RELU activation
            layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
            layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

            # Hidden layer with RELU activation
            layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
            layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

            # Hidden layer with RELU activation
            layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
            layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

            # Output layer with linear activation
            out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
            return out_layer

        # Store layers weight & bias
        weights = {
            'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
            'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
            'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
            'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
        }
        biases = {
            'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
            'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
            'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
            'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
        }

        # Construct model
        pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)
        pred1 = tf.argmax(pred,1)

        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
        #cost = -tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(pred,1e-10,1.0)))
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))

        optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
        hm_epochs = 20

        tf.set_random_seed(1234)
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init) 

            for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
                avg_cost = 0
                total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
                for i in range(total_batch-1):
                    batch_x = train_X[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
                    batch_y = train_Y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]

                    _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                                   y: batch_y})
                    avg_cost += c / total_batch

                label_value = batch_y
                estimate = p
                err = label_value-estimate

                if epoch % display_step == 0:
                    print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                        "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost)
                    print "[*]----------------------------------------------------"
                    for i in xrange(3):
                        print "label value:", label_value[i], \
                                "estimated value:", estimate[i]
                    print "======================================================="

            print "Optimization Finished!"

            #Test model
            #correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            #Calculate accuracy
            #accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
            #print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: test_X, y: test_Y}))


            feed_dict = {X: test_X}
            classification = pred.eval(feed_dict)
            print "Network Prediction:", classification
            print "Classification: ", np.argmax(classification) + 1

            #probabilities=pred1
            #print "probabilities", probabilities.eval(feed_dict={X: test_X}, session=sess)


root = Tk()

ent1 = StringVar()
ent2 = StringVar()
ent3 = StringVar()
ent4 = StringVar()
ent5 = StringVar()
ent6 = StringVar()
ent7 = StringVar()
ent8 = StringVar()
ent9 = StringVar()
ent10 = StringVar()
ent11 = StringVar()
ent12 = StringVar()
ent13 = StringVar()
ent14 = StringVar()

root.geometry("400x600")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```